# How to find the name of an image from a CollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I select an image from a CollectionView and this cell, I want to get the name of that image and save it to CloudKit. My main question is how to get the name of the selected image?

This is my CollectionViewCell:

```
class AddImageViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var addListImageView: UIImageView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width * 0.2
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
}
```

Some of my AddListViewController:

```
class AddListViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageArray : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Images/do001.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do002.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do003.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do004.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do005.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do006.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do007.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do008.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do009.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do010.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do011.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do012.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do013.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do014.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do015.png")!,
                                  UIImage(named: "Images/do016.png")!]

    let selectedImage = 0
```

And here I want to get the name of the image file:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = addImageCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AddImageViewCell
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    var imageInCell = cell.addListImageView.image

    print("\(String(describing: imageInCell))")
}
```

Here CellForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : AddImageViewCell = addImageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AddImageCell", for: indexPath) as! AddImageViewCell
    cell.addListImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: how about storing the names in your model as well?

Comment: Don't read from the cell, read from your datasource. I'd instead do: `var imageArray = ["Images/do000.png", "..."...]`, in `cellForRowAt:`: `let image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])`, and in `didSelect:`: `let imageName = imageArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @Larme Post an answer.

Comment: I tend to be cautious, and wait for a potential issue where the author might say that it's not as simple as `imageArray[indexPath.row]` and might need help on the architecture of it with that. I don't like to make that much assumptions :p

Comment: just show the code cellforRowAtIndexPath, everything will be clear @user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this extension,

1. it creates a property `name`  and set it value using custom `init`,
2. if you did't use the custom `init` it will return empty `String`

> ```
>  extension UIImage {
>     convenience init?(named: String, saveName: Bool) {
>         self.init(named: named)
>         if saveName {
>             self.name = named
>         }
>     }
>     struct Name {
>         static var name: String = ""
>     }
>     var name: String {
>         get {
>             return Name.name
>         }
>         set(newValue) {
>             Name.name = newValue
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

**Usage:**

```
let img = UIImage(named: "test.png", saveName: true)

img?.name // "test.png"

// With image view
let imageView = UIImageView(image: img)
imageView.image?.name
```

Comment: this extension is not limited to UICollectionView and can be used for all UIImage type instances

Comment: This does not work if you have more than one image. There's only one name used by every UIImage instance you create. The name will only be of the most recently created image.

Comment: he want to use it once each time in didSelect

Comment: You are using a `static var`. Just do `let img1 = UIImage(named: "test1.png", saveName: true); let img2 = UIImage(named: "test2.png", saveName: true);`, check the values of `img1.name` it's `test2.png`, not `test1.png`. So it's not working. Also, try to use the array as used by the author `imageArray`. What's the name of each image with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the value from the cells. Cells are reused. Instead, use your model.

I'd suggest to do:

```
var imageNameArray: [String] = ["Images/do001.png", "Images/do002.png", ...]
```

In `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`:

```
let imageName = imageNameArray[indexPath.item]
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
cell.addListImageView.image = image
```

In `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`:

```
let selectedImageName = imageNameArray[indexPath.item]
```